# "java.exe" exited with code 1 error when enabled proguard on xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, proguard, android-proguard

I am getting this error continuously when generating apk with release configuration, I have tried different ways but could not succeed. I have also change the heap size. but still no success. I have also installed **name.atsushieno.proguard.facebook** nugget package.

Comment: Please post your [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output).